# what is the red arrow on the left of the line numbers in Sublime

Tags: sublimetext3

[image: see the red arrow on the left of the picture]

What does the red arrow mean in Sublime Text editor between line 13 and 14?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This appears to be a new feature in Sublime 3.2 called *diff marker*. The red arrow is one of three *diff markers* indicating that the `line before this was deleted`, the two others having to do with adding new lines or modifying existing ones.

From a simple experiment it seems the reference is the state of the file when you opened it in Sublime, but there is also a way to integrate it with Git version control.

Official source: https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/incremental_diff.html#diff_markers